# Simulation Heston Model to value optinos

Tags: r, model, simulation

I need to perform a option price simulation using Heston model via R codes. The problem is that the code that I used produced warnings "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" and the results were very bad.

Here is the code:

```
m <- 1000 #time steps
T <- 0.5 #time (6 months)
dt <- T/m
kappa <- 1.15
theta <- 0.0348
r <- 0 
sigma <- 0.39
V.0 <- 0.0348
rho <- -0.64
S.0 <- 1
K <- seq(0.8,1.2,0.1) #Strike prices from 0.8 to 1.2
totsim <- 1000


S <- V <- C <- matrix(0,m,1)
V[1] <- V.0
S[1] <- S.0

z1 <- rnorm(m)
z2 <- rnorm(m)

for(i in 2:m){
  V[i] <- V[i-1] + kappa*(theta-V[i-1])*dt + sigma*sqrt(V[i-1])*sqrt(dt)*z2
  V[i] <- abs(V[i])
  S[i] <- S[i-1] + r*S[i-1]*dt + S[i-1]*sqrt(V[i-1])*sqrt(dt)*(rho*z1+sqrt(1-rho^2)*z2)
}
```

Any suggestion to fix this problem? And what should I do next to simulate call price?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `a` and `b`?

Comment: In fact is kappa and theta. I just edited the post

Comment: Your Error turns up, because you try to put a vector of length 1000 in one cell. That's not possible therefore just the first element of the vector will be written in your matrices `V`and `S`. For each i the result is a vector of length 1000 because in your formular you multiply by `z1`or `z2` (vectors of length 1000). Here is your problem in small `mat <- matrix(0,1,1)
mat[1] <- 2*c(2,3)` The matrix just get filled with the first element, maybe thats he reason for your *bad* results. I dont know Heston Model, so I don't know if your formular is ment to do this.